# Naming convention for matrix that is not inverted

Tags: matrices, convention

There is the inverse matrix, but how do we call the matrix before it became a inverse matrix?
I called it normal matrix before but it sounds confusing cause normal makes it sound that it has to do with the 0 to 1 range.

Comment: Before $A^{-1}$ "became a inverse matrix", it was named $A$. A matrix $A$ is called normal, if $AA^*=A^*A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely not normal matrix, because calling a matrix "normal" implies [a very specific mathematical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). Instead, I would simply call it the "original matrix" to refer to the matrix before it became inverted. However, it is preferable if you give a matrix a variable name, so the original matrix can be called $A$ and the inverted matrix can be called $A^{-1}$ without ambiguity.